# Populate a variable in controller with single row data from a query

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I have in a Codeigniter 4 controller this code:

```
    $competicion =$db->table('competiciones')
    ->select('*')
    ->where('competiciones.slug', $blog_slug)
    ->get()->getRowArray();
```

How can I get and save in a variable id_competicion value, for example? I try this code but it is wrong:

```
    $competicionid = $competicion->[competicion_id];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getRowArray()` returns an array, the correct approach to retrieve an array value would be:

```
$competicionid = $competicion['competicion_id'];
```

another possibility would be to use `getRow()`, which returns an object. To retrieve an object value you could use:

```
$competicionid = $competicion->competicion_id;
```

read more: [Generating Query Results: Result Rows](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html?highlight=getrowarray#result-rows)